# Making a population density map from tabulated (.txt) data in R?

Tags: r, cartography, excel, density, zip-codes

I have California population density data from from the U.S. Census in an Excel file.

The spatial information is provided in ZIP Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTAs).
How do I plot a population density map with that data using R?

This is what I have been doing:

[dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/thgwws1urw000c4/mre.txt)

```
library(maptools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(classInt)
library(maps)

## set the working directory.
setwd("../Downloads")

## load the file
pop <- read.table("mre.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep=",")

#select color palette and the number colors (levels of income) to represent on the map
colors <- brewer.pal(9, "YlOrRd")

#set breaks for the 9 colors 
brks<<-classIntervals(pop$POP10, n=9, style="quantile")
brks<- brks$brks

#plot the map
plot(pop, col=colors[findInterval(pop$POP10, brks,all.inside=TRUE)], axes=F)
```

I also tried this other way:

```
CaliforniaZTACs<-readShapePoly("[tl_2010_06_zcta510.shp][2]")
plot(CaliforniaZTACs)
CaliforniaZTACs
```

but could not associate a population density value from my dataset to the location ID of the tl_2010-06-zcta510.shp file.

Comment: What kind of spatial information is in your excel sheet? Point locations? Just convert it to `SpatialPointsDataframe` in R and use `plot`

Comment: Quick google let me stumble on this website where you apparently can download shapefile: http://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html See if this helps you. Based on the ZCTA you could make a join then

Comment: Also please show us what you have tried so far in terms of your R code.

Comment: @AndreSilva: I added the dataset. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The more populated area seems to be the regions of San Francisco and Los Angeles, right?

```
library(ggplot2)

pop <- read.table("mre.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep=",")
pop <- data.frame(pop)

ggplot(data=pop,aes(x=LONG,y=LAT)) + geom_point(data=pop, aes(size=POP10)) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can also add a Google Maps (or OpenStreetMap) image as background with `R` `get_map` function and plot it with `ggmap` package + your data.

```
library(ggmap)

x <- get_map(location="California", zoom=6, maptype="terrain")

ggmap(x, extent="normal") + geom_point(data=pop, aes(x=LONG,y=LAT,size=POP10)) + theme_bw()
```

[image]